# In react app could not check if the item exist to identify text shown in button

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout/Layout";
import { Checkbox, Radio } from "antd";
import { useCart } from "../../context/cart";


const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [cart, setCart] = useCart()

 
    
    return (
        {products?.map((product, index) => (
                            <div className="product-card" key={index}>
                                <img src={`http://localhost:4000/api/product/photo/${product._id}`} />
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h3 className="card-title">{product.name}</h3>
                                    <p className="card-price">${product.price}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-btn">
                                    <button onClick={() => navigate(`/product/${product.slug}`)}>
                                        More Details 
                                    </button>
                                    <button onClick={() => {
                                        setCart([...cart, product])
                                        localStorage.setItem(
                                            "cart",
                                            JSON.stringify([...cart, product])
                                        )
                                        toast.success("Item added to cart")
                                    }}>
                                       {/* {cart.find((c) => c === product ? "Already in Cart" : "Add to Cart")}  */}
                                       Add to Cart
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}


export default Home
```

I am trying to figure out whether the `cart` already includes the product in the looping then shows different text in button in the React app. I may want to ask what is the best way to check if the variable already includes the product to identify what text to be shown?

Answer (score 0):

This code can work only if you have access to the cart directly.
Doing the filtering inside the render means that everytime you will change the app state, the filter will be done too. If you have 100 items, means the filter will be called 100 times on every rend.

So do it outside the render

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout/Layout";
import { Checkbox, Radio } from "antd";
import { useCart } from "../../context/cart";


const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const [cart, setCart] = useCart()
    for (let product of products) {
        if(cart.filter(item_ =>item_._id === product._id).length > 0){
            //item is in the cart as well;
            product.is_In_Cart = true
            
    
        }
    }
 
    
    return (
        {products?.map((product, index) => (
                            <div className="product-card" key={index}>
                                <img src={`http://localhost:4000/api/product/photo/${product._id}`} />
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h3 className="card-title">{product.name}</h3>
                                    <p className="card-price">${product.price}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="card-btn">
                                    <button onClick={() => navigate(`/product/${product.slug}`)}>
                                        More Details 
                                    </button>
                                    <button onClick={() => {
                                        setCart([...cart, product])
                                        localStorage.setItem(
                                            "cart",
                                            JSON.stringify([...cart, product])
                                        )
                                        toast.success("Item added to cart")
                                    }}>
                                        {product.is_In_Cart === true ? "Already in Cart" : "Add to Cart")}  
                                       
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))}


export default Home
```

An other alternative, is to but the Item Component out side the parent component. So that you can render the Item Component as a separate component and then call the check_If_It_Is_In_the_Cart function from the Item(Product) component.

Comment: But how to do the filter inside product loop to identify ```is_In_Cart```?

Comment: Have edit. Don't hesitate  for further explanation. and rate in case it works